# Trilogy where people went to another world via portals and had gems embedded in them

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a trilogy (I believe) of books that I read as a kid. The details are fuzzy a bit but I remember the following:

1. People were portaled from our world to another
2. Each person who came had a gemstone embedded in their body (one was I. The head and another in the head)
3. They were fighting against some sort of darkness that swooped down at night and ate people
4. There was a wizard who brought them
5. The spines were bright neon colors like orange and pink

I know that's not probably very helpful but fingers crossed

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions for asking story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if there are any other clues you can recall.

Answer (score 7):

This feels like a mixup of two different book series.

In [the Darwath trilogy by Barbara Hambly](https://www.goodreads.com/series/50578-darwath) there is a darkness that swoops down at night and eats people, and people are brought from our world by the wizard Ingold Inglorion to deal with the problem. So this matches very closely with most of the points you remember except that there are no gems embedded in heads or bodies. The first book looks like this if it helps jog your memory:

[image: Darwath]

This was previously identified in the question [60's/70's Trio of books about being attacked by giant bats that take away your ability to think](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197606/60s-70s-trio-of-books-about-being-attacked-by-giant-bats-that-take-away-your-a)

There is a different series that has people with gems embedded in their bodies. This is [the Wizards series by Simon Hawke](https://www.goodreads.com/series/42666-wizard) and was perviously the subject of the question [Fantasy novel where characters have gemstones implanted in their bodies. Female baddie is trying to 'harvest' them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161918/fantasy-novel-where-characters-have-gemstones-implanted-in-their-bodies-female) However this is a long series not a trilogy, and there is no darkness that swoops down and eats people.

The Wizards books do have brightly coloured covers. For example the original first book (subsequently two prequels were written) looks like this:

[image: The Wizards]

Comment: I do remember two more things: the girl in the story ends up in a romantic relationship with the wizard at the end and there isn’t a scene in one of the books where they are trapped in a tower with the darkness thingies trying to get in and one of the gemstone weirdest creates a shield against them. Oh and there’s are 3-4 weilders

Comment: @XhexyZavier in the third of the Darwath trilogy the girl, Gil, falls in love with the wizard Ingold, so that strongly suggests you are remembering the Darwath trilogy.