# Novel or series about humans who deal with monsters who come out at night

Tags: story-identification

I recall reading a book or series of novels published in the 70s or 80s about an embattled group of humans who were struggling with monstrous creatures who only appeared at night and the days are getting shorter.

I'm thinking this was in the fantasy genre as I recall a map at the beginning of the book.  In some ways similar to the "Riddick/Pitch Black" film series. Very atmospheric, but not sci-fi, and definitely without Vin Diesel.

Comment: This also makes me think of *30 Days of Night*, where vampires move to Barrow, Alaska so they can enjoy no sunlight for about a month. Doesn't match the timeframe (the comic didn't come out until 2002; at least one novel has been published, but that'd be even later), and it really starts when the days are gone.

Comment: I'm not confident enough of my memories of the book to make this a true answer, but how about Barbara Hambly's 'The Time of the Dark'?  It's fantasy, I believe the evil 'Dark' creatures attack at night, the humans are besieged by them in a cave fortress. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176277.The_Time_of_the_Dark

Comment: I think that the Barbara Hambly series may be it!  If not it is eerily close.  If I can find a Kindle sample or something that shows the map then I can confirm tomorrow!

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79002/what-book-has-a-man-in-a-world-on-the-brink-of-an-ice-age-with-a-wizard-mentor (pending OP final confirmation)

Comment: @LAK that should be an answer. You don't need to be absolutely sure of the book to post an answer. Just post the evidence you have for it. I've done that many times and sometimes my guess has proved correct.

Comment: @BrianW.Spolarich [is this the map you remember from the book](https://i.imgur.com/5h8FQEz.gif)? This is the map from LAK's suggetion of The Time of the Dark.

Comment: @JohnRennie This isn't the map I remember but it was 30+ years ago and I don't have that kind of memory.  I'll accept this as answered.  Thanks @LAK!

Comment: While there was a previous story identification post that turns out to be the answer to mine, my post and the research I did would never have found that post in my mind.  Seems like a borderline duplicate to me.

Comment: @BrianW.Spolarich, regarding the duplicate status of your question, be advised that these are marked primarily as a way of helping future seekers find and confirm the correct answer. As you note, the particular memories of a story are often quite different for different people, so don't worry about having missed the previous answers. Welcome to the Stack!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that this is Barbara Hambly's [*The Time of the Dark*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176277.The_Time_of_the_Dark), the first of her 'Darwath' books.  It's fantasy, with real-world characters being brought over to the fantasy world.  There's a Gandalf-like wizard named Ingold.  I believe that the evil 'Dark' creatures attack at night, the humans are besieged by them in a cave fortress.  I think the world is entering an ice age, which may be related to your memories of shortening days.

[image: The Time of the Dark front cover]

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like the last of F. Paul Wilson's Repairman Jack novels, [*Nightworld*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightworld_(novel)):

The description Wikipedia gives is:

> Rasalom returns in reincarnated form to transform the Earth into unrelenting hell. Rasalom is shortening the daylight hours and letting loose a plague of ever-more-fearsome flesh-eating monsters that prey on the world's populace during the ever-lengthening nights.

This was published in 1992 so it's a bit later than you recall, but the description matches.

Comment: Interesting.  This is definitely not the story I'm thinking of as there was no reincarnation trope.  I also remember a fantasy-style map at the beginning now that I'm remembering a bit more.  I'll edit my question regarding the genre since my description was inaccurate.