# 90s(?) book series about two people transported to a parallel medieval world, she joins city watch, he becomes wizard

Tags: story-identification, books

I must have read his in the nineties.  I think it was a series of books.

The first book starts off with a woman in a cabin in a modern-day American desert. I think a biker dude turns up, and then a wizard appears with a baby, and transports them to a parallel medieval world. The woman joins the city watch, protecting the baby, and the biker dude becomes an apprentice to the wizard.

I remember one scene where the biker dude casts a spell to change his appearance to a dung beetle, to sneak past some guards thinking it would be inconspicuous, but the locals had never seen a dung beetle before.

The book was written in English.

Comment: The description in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/49273) sounds fairly similar but the answers given don't have the wizard bringing in a baby (also not sure about the girl joining a city watch). Any input on this?

Comment: @Jenayah Based on the cover description, that other question is the same book -- but has no accepted answer.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Possibly the [Time of the Dark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176277.The_Time_of_the_Dark), part one of Barbara Hambly's Darwath Trilogy? The land of Darwath, a fantasy-medieval type kingdom on another world is under attack by the shapeshifting alien Dark Ones, and the wizard Ingold flees to Earth with the baby prince. Ending up at a cabin in the California desert Ingold meets a woman named Gil and the mechanic Rudy. Somehow the three end up back in Darwath, where Rudy discovers a talent for magic. I've only read the first of the trilogy, don't know how the rest turns out.

Comment: It is definitely the Darwath Series. The dung beetle incident occurs on the third book, The Armies of Daylight.

Comment: Thanks for the quick identification.  I had forgotten the names of the main characters, but those are them.